# Is Firebase Crashlytics suited to log failed API responses?

Tags: android, crashlytics

In my Android app, I need to log failed API responses so that I can analyze the reason of failure.

1. Is Firebase Crashlytics a good choice for that? Because mostly people use Crashlytics to log App crashes.
2. Is there any guideline from Google/Android as to what should be the use of Crashlytics and what it should not be used for ?

I'm asking this here because I couldn't find this in any documentation.

Comment: Yes, you can add the firebase crashytics for logging the responses.
Or you can simply create a file and write all the data there.

Comment: I want a Dashboard too where my teammates also can see the APi responses easily. Crashlytics gives a Dashboard. Logging to a file will be a lot of unfiltered data in one place. Have you tried to log API responses to Crashlytics ? @AnamicaBisht

Comment: Read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#java_2